# Trying to find a specific book about clones

Tags: story-identification, clones

So, since Orphan Black came out - and I haven seen it but the premise of it - this old book has been niggling at me. I remember reading it in the late nineties/early millenium.  It was about a girl who discovers she is a clone, and I believe she's the fourth clone. And all of the clones, as well as the original girl, have died of an illness that the original girl had herself. The story follows the clone as she pieces together who the other clones where and what the connection was (that they all die of the same illness) until eventually...at the end of the book, she finds a cure left behind with her name on it.  At the very, very end of the book, it is discovered that there are more cures, with other names on them, indicating that their are other clones, still alive, who do not know they are in danger.

One of the themes of the clones was that they had names following the letters of the alphabet, I believe the main character's name started with an 'E' or an 'F'.

I've looked everywhere, and keep finding other clone books but not this one, I'd really

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Watchers I.D. by Peter Lerangis - Book Cover 01] [image: Watchers I.D. by Peter Lerangis - Book Cover 02]

Could be "**Watchers: I.D.**" by [Peter Lerangis](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?5398).

From the author's [website](http://peterlerangis.com/about-the-books/watchers/):

> The watchers see things that others can't see. In this installment,
> **a young girl discovers she is a clone**, and has **only days to live** unless she finds the secrets of her creators.

Another [synopsis](http://www.openroadmedia.com/id) throws up a few more details:

> As Eve approaches her fourteenth birthday, something begins to
> feel very wrong. **While skiing, she sees a girl about her age die
> suddenly of a heart attack**.

She makes a startling discovery:

> A few days later, Eve learns that the girl’s sudden death is part of
> a pattern of **fourteen-year-olds dying of strange causes**, based on a chromosomal defect. **One of the dead is Alexis, a girl who looks
> exactly like Eve**.

The following extract from the book describes Eve finding the antidotes:

> Eve reached in. She turned other vials and read the labels. CAROLINE.
> ALEXIS.
>
> EVE.
>
> The one meant for her.
>
> She lifted it out.
>
> “Wait!”, Martina cried. “What if it's not the right one?”
>
> Eve paused.
>
> Her mind was clouded.
>
> *What if?*
>
> The wrong one meant death.

*The five clones are Alexis, Bryann, Caroline, Danielle and Eve*. And only Eve survives in the end - or so she thinks. From the last page of the book:

> *“Eve!”*
>
> She turned, slowly, painfully, to the person standing by the bed.
>
> A down coat, a wool scarf.
>
> A face.
>
> *No.*
>
> *Impossible.*
>
> “Hi,” the girl said. “You don’t know me…”
>
> *A dream.*
>
> *ABCDE. No one left. I am the end of the line.*
>
> “… but my name is Francesca…”

You can go through sample chapters [here](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/sample/read/9781453248225) or [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0590109987).

Comment: You found it! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @Simba - Glad to help! Whenever you're back, do select the "tick mark" on your left and mark this one as "answered".

Comment: It's nice to see a question on stories actually being answered- normally they're obscure and impossible to find :)